# How to create a lightning component button to create an opportunity line item

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I've created a component file with:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"  access="global" >
    <ui:button label="Create Door" press="{! c.createRecord}"/>
</aura:component>
```

And a controller:

```
({
    createRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityAPIName": "OpportunityLineItem",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'OpportunityId':'ID',
                'Product2Id':'ProdID',
                'Quantity':'1',
                'TotalPrice':'1'
        }
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

When I click the button I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentDef' of null
```

I've tried adding "componentDef" as a variable in a couple different places, but at this point I'm stuck - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `ui:button` has been deprecated as of API 47, see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:button/example) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDef` errors refer to internal library code, not anything you've specifically missed.

OpportunityLineItem is [not supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) (see "The following objects are not supported by force:createRecord"). This is causing the error you're looking at. You'll have to build your own component instead.

Also note that ui elements have been [deprecated](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm) and will be removed around May 2021; please use the lightning version instead (lightning:button).

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @sfdcfox, I have done a quick check for workaround on creating Opportunity Line Item using button of type Lightning Component.

You can use [navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) to navigate to url which opens the new form for opportunity line item on load of aura component using init event.

```
https://***.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/OpportunityLineItem/new
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason, why directly using the url "/lightning/o/OpportunityLineItem/new" above gives the following error "Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 276456685-187532 (-1413120216)"